# Does dereferencing a structure pointer as a different structure's pointer alter output if I change compiler?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

In the following pseudo code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct _apple
{
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
} apple;

typedef struct _orange
{
    int a;
    int b;
} orange;

typedef struct _grape
{
    int a;
} grape;

void main()
{
    apple a1;
    orange o1;

    a1.a =1;
    a1.b =2;
    a1.c =3;
    o1.a =4;

    void * fruit[] = {&a1, &o1};

    grape *app = (grape*)fruit[0];

    printf ("\nRead: %d    ", app->a);
    app = (grape*)fruit[1];

    printf ("\nRead: %d    ", app->a);
}
```

The structure grape is a subset of apple and orange in the sense that it contain the element in the same order as in apple and in orange. This program is giving the expected output as 1 and 4. But is there a chance for this approach to fail with a different compiler or any other environment-specific change?

Comment: This is a truly horrible idea - use a union for your common struct fields.

Comment: side note: it's perfectly ok to write: `typedef struct something {...} something;`. I.e., you don't need to give the struct a different name from the `typedef`ed name (as in `_orange` vs `orange`).

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but some mean compiler could "optimize" away your structs' members if they are not used...

Comment: Not only is it ok to reuse the same name (as @Shahbaz mentions) using identifiers startin with an underscore in global scope is a no-no. Such identifiers are reserved for the compiler.

Comment: @JensGustedt, C11, 7.1.3 says: _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ This means that a name such as `_name` will (should) never be exposed to your file by any header (or during link) and I believe it would also mean that it's ok if you use it in a file, if you make sure it's contained just to that file. The wording is a bit vague to me, but that has been my understanding. Your comment is very true though, if the structs were defined in a header rather than the source file itself.

Comment: @Shahbaz, this has nothing to do with header file or not, the restriction applies for all such identifiers in file scope, the wording is not vague at all to me. The reason for such a restriction is that the compiler is allowed to use any such identifiers internally and for linking purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `union` to handle all types:

```
typedef struct {
    /* Common elements */
    int a;
    /* Type specific */
    union {
        struct {
            char b;
            float c;
        } apple;
        struct {
            int b;
        } orange;
    } special;
} fruit;

fruit or;
or.a = 1;
or.special.orange.b = 2;
fruit * f = &or;
```

Or mimick object inheritance:

```
/* Common elements (base class) */
typedef struct {
    int a;
} fruit;

/* Extended types */
typedef struct {
    fruit parent; /* Must be first */
} grape;

typedef struct {
    fruit parent; /* Must be first */
    int b;
} orange;

orange or;
or.parent.a = 1;
or.b = 2;
fruit * f1 = (fruit*)&or;
fruit * f2 = &or.parent; /* alternate type safe way */
```

Or use C++ to get proper inheritance.

Comment: The project is constrained in C. And the structures are standard one who's template is not supposed to be edited :(

Comment: In that case there is really not any alternative. If you want to do conversion from one type to another, the portable way is to copy stucture fields manually, one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast anything if you know that your pointer points to something that is not really indicated by the pointer. But you should never cast when you assume that the compiler has compiled something in a specific way.

Your approach will fail when any of the structure elements is changed. It violates the requirement for maintainability. Your approach can fail on any new compiler variant.

Comment: The real code is having around 10-20 structures where only the last 1 or 2 elements are changing. So the think is that dereffering all these structure instances exept for that last 1 or 2 elements can save thousands of lines of code in my specific application...But with compilers this can make a problem then i will be left out with no options...